# Updated list of bad/overused passwords

Tags: web-application, passwords, password-policy

I am building a website, and I'd like to make sure the users don't put an overused password like `password` or `password1`.. or [any of these](https://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2006/12/realworld_passw.html)

Is there a place that constantly analyzes hacked websites passwords list and have a DB of the password usage statistics?

Comment: Hi Nick, this question is not really a good fit for SE, as it stands now. Perhaps you might want to change to something like "How can I prevent bad passwords", or "What should I do to prevent bad passwords".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a [article](http://xato.net/passwords/more-top-worst-passwords/) with the data I hope you needed:

There you can find [two](http://xato.net/files/10k%20most%20common.zip) [files](http://xato.net/files/10k%20most%20common%20with%20frequency.zip) with password and small statistics

Comment: I also wonder if this kind of research keeps updating

Comment: Sadly to say, but most probably no. I found the link to this site from http://howsecureismypassword.net/

Comment: The password analysis is done on password lists leaked from security compromises at major websites. When more passwords get disclosed, the analysis does get updated, but hopefully these sites learn their lesson and start hashing passwords.

Comment: As for my list at xato.net, I do keep collecting passwords every day. I am currently working on improving my parser but as soon as I finish that I have a few gigabytes of passwords dumps to process. The fact is, however, that the top 1,000 passwords lists have hardly changed much over the last 20 years.

Comment: thanks for nice job, you are doing. If you need any help with parser, I am willing to help :-)

Comment: thanks @MarkBurnett . Nice to know what the list is being updated. Hopefully you will be the first to see a shift in user passwords and towards better security